# Como configurar o "gdb" para a sintaxe Intel

Tags: sintaxe, gdb

Estou tentando configurar o `gdb` para a sintaxe `intel`, entretanto estou obtendo a seguinte mensagem :

```
Ambiguous set command "dis intel": disable-randomization, disassemble-next-line,
disassembly-flavor, disconnected-dprintf...
```

Estou tentado os procedimentos abaixo, mas quando executo o segundo procedimento a mensagem acima aparece.

```
root@debian:/home/novousuario# gdb -q
(gdb) set dis intel
(gdb) quit
root@debian:/home/novousuario# echo "set dis intel" > ~/.gdbinit 
root@debian:/home/novousuario# cat ~/.gdbinit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está ocorrendo porque o comando está abreviado ("dis").

Tente a forma completa do comando (no modo interativo e/ou no arquivo `~/.gdbinit`):

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
```

Comment: Perfeito, manow.. o que será ?  Devo realizar algum tipo de configuração para aceitar as abreviações ?

Comment: Não, não precisa. O `gdb` não aceitou a abreviação porque tem vários comandos que começam com "dis" (erro de ambiguidade). Mas se você abreviar, por exemplo, para `set disassembly intel`, vai funcionar :)

Comment: Massa vlw... Saquei...